# Trying to query across collections in google Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve data from one collection depending on data held in another. If the userUID in my attendance collection equals the userUID in my student collection I would like to retrieve the name of the student. Is this possible?

Comment: if you have a document with same userId in attendance and student collection, then you can query student using `WhereEqualTo(fieldName,value)` like `db.collection("student")
        .whereEqualTo("userId", "idValue").get()`

Comment: can I combine these queries of two collections into one query or how is this possible

Comment: No its not possible to combine queries of two collection into one query.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with Firestore.  Firestore queries are limited to a documents in a single collection.  You would have to perform multiple gets or queries.

Comment: Is there anyway at all to query within a query even to try and retrieve this data and make a connection between the two collections.

Comment: As I said, write multiple queries to get the data you need.

Comment: is there anyway to write a function within a query to retrieve data maybe.

Comment: No, you have to perform multiple queries.

Comment: And to add to this is there any way to write queries within other queries

Answer (score 0):

According to multiple Google Firebase engineers, querying across collections is not at all possible, despite the Firestore documentation that says:

> If you need to query data across collections, use
>   root-level collections.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model?authuser=3

I would suggest that Google rewrite this part of their documentation because that sentences literally infers the opposite. It should read along the lines of:

> If you need to query data across collections, not happening.